# CSS Media Queries not behaving as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, css, media-queries

I have converted my website to android compatibility with using of CSS3 Media Queries(I just changed CSS only). My android device dimensions are 1280x 600. Its working fine in android devices.

But when I turned my desktop to 1280 resolution the design is changed (like how i wrote for android device). But it shouldn't come like that.

Only for devices i have used the css below
@media only screen and (max-device-width:1280px){
}

What is the mistake i have done?

Answer (score 0):

That query affects every device with a max with of 1280px, not only mobile.

Comment: so whats the solution? is there any possible way in css declaration to detect only android devices?

Comment: I don't think targeting Android-only devices it's possible, but try using "handheld" for mobile.